# how to store recent data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am using tabbarviewcontroller and i am doing some operations on 3 out of 5 view controllers and i want to store data from every controller when ever i did something and i want to display the stored information in 4th view controller using tableview 
(example : like recent dialed list in iphone native phone app )

what is the best method to achieve it ?

thanks for help

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store globally in appDelegate

```
yourAppDelegate *appObj=(yourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
appObj.anyObjectWhichYouDeclaredInAppDelegate = Something;
```

You can assign or retrieve the object in whichever viewcontroller you want by using the above code.